# How to make PSCmdlet bool parameter to work like a flag?

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

Using System.Management.Automation you can create custom PSCmdlets in C#.
Now if you create boolean parameter like this:

```
[Parameter()]
public bool ShowDefinition { get; set; }
```

You have to invoke cmdlet like this:

```
PS> Get-CustomValues -ShowDefinition 1
```

But I would like to invoke it without passing value to -ShowDefinition. The same way as -Debug works.
Like this:

```
PS> Get-CustomValues -ShowDefinition
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6):

OK, I found the answer.

You have to use SwitchParameter.

```
[Parameter]
public SwitchParameter ShowDefinition { get; set; }

protected override void ProcessRecord(){
    if(ShowDefinition.ToBool()){
    ...
    }
}
```